# Changing shell from /bin/bash to /bin/zsh disappears programming tools?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I became very interested in Linux and wanted to customize my terminal with ZSH and powerlevel10k, but after changing and logging out, the programming tools [disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLeLe.jpg). I tried very hard to understand the reason but it did not work. I am not very familiar with the $PATH command and I do not know if it works or not. Thanks for your help.
image link => https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLeLe.jpg

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: `PATH` is a variable, not a command, and the shell you run determines which configuration files (which modify the value of `PATH`) are sourced.

Answer (score 0):

Changing default shell to ZSH can help
first find the path of your ZSh shell.

```
type -a zsh
```

then change it

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

now log out and log in again. One can close the Terminal app and reopen it.

Comment: type -a zsh gives me these two result

zsh is /usr/bin/zsh
zsh is /bin/zsh

and after change 

chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
or
chsh -s /bin/zsh 

and logout. The problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

After digging, I finally realized that the files that were installed with SNAP are not displayed. When I installed the file in Deb format, it became known.